# How can I retrieve settings from a design dialog for use in a dialog?

Tags: aem

I am working on creating a component with both a dialog and a design_dialog.  In the design_dialog, I am using a pathfield widget to allow a designer to select a root path.  In the dialog, I am trying to use another pathfield widget to allow the author to select a page under the path that was selected by the designer in the design dialog.  (Basically I am trying to set the rootPath property of the widget in the dialog to equal the path the designer chose in the design_dialog.)  It seems like it should be something simple to do, but I'm having no luck.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code here ? This may help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AEM uses ExtJS for the widgets (in Classic mode).

Here is a resource to get you started:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/widgets.html

Here is the API doc:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html

And maybe have a look at this: http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-04-07/cq-dialog-dynamically-generate-rootpath/